# Embedding Forms on Sites

Tags: javascript, deployment

I am building a form that I want users to be able to embedded on their site using a snippet of code, something like:

```html
<div id="my-form"></div>
<script src="my-bundle.js"></script>
```

What would be the best way of doing this. I am planning on building out the form using a front-end JS framework but other then that any help (how to deploy, best approach to implement) would be appreciated.

Comment: Something like: ???? did you forget to put something in your question?

Comment: The `iframe` element can be used to embed other websites... otherwise, you can show what your form looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Let them embed those 2 lines of code.
Script's src should point to your hosted js file where you will have a self execution function with the code like:

```
(function () {
    var formData = '<form action="http://submit-url">'
        + '<div><input type="text" name="FirstName" /></div>'
        + '<div><input type="text" name="LastName" /></div>'
        + '<div><input type="text" name="Email" /></div>'
        + '<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>'
        + '</form>';

    document.getElementById("my-form").innerHTML = formData;
})();
```